# After adding a UISlider to UINavigationbar, it displays wrong in landscape mode. How to correct?

Tags: ios, objective-c, slider, navigationbar

I'm doing my own video player on iPhone. I add a `UISlider` to `UINavigationbar` as process bar.

**code:**

```
IBOutlet UISlider* mScrubber;

......

UIBarButtonItem *scrubberItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:mScrubber];

[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: scrubberItem, nil]];
```

It works right when starting in portrait mode. But when starting in landscape mode, the process bar is still as wide as in portrait mode. The screenshot is [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3zSzVUgsG-FMW1vS3VRdEo2M0U/edit?usp=sharing)

Can anybody tell me how to correct it?

Thanks in advance!

Ben

Answer (score 0):

It's simple to do in the storyboard. Just add the slider to the navigation bar of a controller that has a push segue connected to it. It will automatically stretch across the whole navigation bar, but will make room for the back button when it appears, and respond correctly to rotation.

Comment: Thanks rdelmar! Unfortunately, I don't use storyboard. Is their any functions or properties to set this?

Comment: Finally, I solved the question. I added a toolbar to the xib file and added a slider to the toolbar. It works well! The reason I didn't use navigationbar is it can not be hidden. I don't know why.